# How do I connect a bno055 chip to a Linux pc via an FTDI UART breakout sensor?

Tags: sensor, uart, linux, ftdi

I want to create a C++ (or C) program that reads in a stream of Quaternion data from the [bno055 Adafruit chip](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor/overview).

My set-up at the moment has an Ubuntu PC as the controller. Plugged into the PC is a [USB to UART breakout bridge](https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT230X.html) which creates a serial port that (in theory) can be opened and read from in `/dev/ttyUSB*`. The orientation sensor is then wired into the UART end of the bridge (via a breadboard) in accordance with the wiring diagram found on [this Adafruit webpage](https://learn.adafruit.com/bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor-with-raspberry-pi-and-beaglebone-black/hardware), meaning the UART bridge has replaced the Raspberry Pi pinouts. In short: `Linux Machine -> USB -> UART -> breadboard -> Orientation Sensor`

Currently, having installed the [D2XX drivers](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) for the FTDI chip (the chip in the USB bridge) and having made sure it is running these drivers by unloading the default drivers when the USB bridge is connected (`sudo rmmod ftdi_sio` & `sudo rmmod usbserial`) I can run provided example code that is included with D2XX drivers that reads device data using EEPROM data methods.
The files that do this are the following:

main.c

```
/*
    To build use the following gcc statement 
    (assuming you have the d2xx library in the /usr/local/lib directory).
    gcc -o read main.c -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib
    */    

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "../../ftd2xx.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FT_STATUS   ftStatus;
    FT_HANDLE   ftHandle0;
    int iport;
    static FT_PROGRAM_DATA Data;
    static FT_DEVICE ftDevice;
    DWORD libraryVersion = 0;
    int retCode = 0;

    ftStatus = FT_GetLibraryVersion(&libraryVersion);
    if (ftStatus == FT_OK)
    {
        printf("Library version = 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)libraryVersion);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error reading library version.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(argc > 1) {
        sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &iport);
    }
    else {
        iport = 0;
    }
    printf("Opening port %d\n", iport);

    ftStatus = FT_Open(iport, &ftHandle0);
    if(ftStatus != FT_OK) {
        /* 
            This can fail if the ftdi_sio driver is loaded
            use lsmod to check this and rmmod ftdi_sio to remove
            also rmmod usbserial
         */
        printf("FT_Open(%d) failed\n", iport);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("FT_Open succeeded.  Handle is %p\n", ftHandle0);

    ftStatus = FT_GetDeviceInfo(ftHandle0,
                                &ftDevice,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                NULL); 
    if (ftStatus != FT_OK) 
    { 
        printf("FT_GetDeviceType FAILED!\n");
        retCode = 1;
        goto exit;
    }  

    printf("FT_GetDeviceInfo succeeded.  Device is type %d.\n", 
           (int)ftDevice);

    /* MUST set Signature1 and 2 before calling FT_EE_Read */
    Data.Signature1 = 0x00000000;
    Data.Signature2 = 0xffffffff;
    Data.Manufacturer = (char *)malloc(256); /* E.g "FTDI" */
    Data.ManufacturerId = (char *)malloc(256); /* E.g. "FT" */
    Data.Description = (char *)malloc(256); /* E.g. "USB HS Serial Converter" */
    Data.SerialNumber = (char *)malloc(256); /* E.g. "FT000001" if fixed, or NULL */
    if (Data.Manufacturer == NULL ||
        Data.ManufacturerId == NULL ||
        Data.Description == NULL ||
        Data.SerialNumber == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory.\n");
        retCode = 1;
        goto exit;
    }

    ftStatus = FT_EE_Read(ftHandle0, &Data);
    if(ftStatus != FT_OK) {
        printf("FT_EE_Read failed\n");
        retCode = 1;
        goto exit;
    }

    printf("FT_EE_Read succeeded.\n\n");

    printf("Signature1 = %d\n", (int)Data.Signature1);          
    printf("Signature2 = %d\n", (int)Data.Signature2);          
    printf("Version = %d\n", (int)Data.Version);                

    printf("VendorId = 0x%04X\n", Data.VendorId);               
    printf("ProductId = 0x%04X\n", Data.ProductId);
    printf("Manufacturer = %s\n", Data.Manufacturer);           
    printf("ManufacturerId = %s\n", Data.ManufacturerId);       
    printf("Description = %s\n", Data.Description);         
    printf("SerialNumber = %s\n", Data.SerialNumber);           
    printf("MaxPower = %d\n", Data.MaxPower);               
    printf("PnP = %d\n", Data.PnP) ;                    
    printf("SelfPowered = %d\n", Data.SelfPowered);         
    printf("RemoteWakeup = %d\n", Data.RemoteWakeup);           

    if (ftDevice == FT_DEVICE_BM)
    {
        /* Rev4 (FT232B) extensions */
        printf("BM:\n");
        printf("---\n");
        printf("\tRev4 = 0x%X\n", Data.Rev4);                   
        printf("\tIsoIn = 0x%X\n", Data.IsoIn);             
        printf("\tIsoOut = 0x%X\n", Data.IsoOut);               
        printf("\tPullDownEnable = 0x%X\n", Data.PullDownEnable);       
        printf("\tSerNumEnable = 0x%X\n", Data.SerNumEnable);           
        printf("\tUSBVersionEnable = 0x%X\n", Data.USBVersionEnable);       
        printf("\tUSBVersion = 0x%X\n", Data.USBVersion);
    }

    if (ftDevice == FT_DEVICE_2232C) 
    {
        /* Rev 5 (FT2232C) extensions */
        printf("2232RC:\n");
        printf("-------\n");
        printf("\tRev5 = 0x%X\n", Data.Rev5);                   
        printf("\tIsoInA = 0x%X\n", Data.IsoInA);               
        printf("\tIsoInB = 0x%X\n", Data.IsoInB);               
        printf("\tIsoOutA = 0x%X\n", Data.IsoOutA);             
        printf("\tIsoOutB = 0x%X\n", Data.IsoOutB);             
        printf("\tPullDownEnable5 = 0x%X\n", Data.PullDownEnable5);     
        printf("\tSerNumEnable5 = 0x%X\n", Data.SerNumEnable5);     
        printf("\tUSBVersionEnable5 = 0x%X\n", Data.USBVersionEnable5); 
        printf("\tUSBVersion5 = 0x%X\n", Data.USBVersion5);         
        printf("\tAIsHighCurrent = 0x%X\n", Data.AIsHighCurrent);       
        printf("\tBIsHighCurrent = 0x%X\n", Data.BIsHighCurrent);       
        printf("\tIFAIsFifo = 0x%X\n", Data.IFAIsFifo);         
        printf("\tIFAIsFifoTar = 0x%X\n", Data.IFAIsFifoTar);           
        printf("\tIFAIsFastSer = 0x%X\n", Data.IFAIsFastSer);           
        printf("\tAIsVCP = 0x%X\n", Data.AIsVCP);               
        printf("\tIFBIsFifo = 0x%X\n", Data.IFBIsFifo);         
        printf("\tIFBIsFifoTar = 0x%X\n", Data.IFBIsFifoTar);           
        printf("\tIFBIsFastSer = 0x%X\n", Data.IFBIsFastSer);           
        printf("\tBIsVCP = 0x%X\n", Data.BIsVCP);
    }

    if (ftDevice == FT_DEVICE_232R)
    {
        /* Rev 6 (FT232R) extensions */
        printf("232R:\n");
        printf("-----\n");
        printf("\tUseExtOsc = 0x%X\n", Data.UseExtOsc);         // Use External Oscillator
        printf("\tHighDriveIOs = 0x%X\n", Data.HighDriveIOs);           // High Drive I/Os
        printf("\tEndpointSize = 0x%X\n", Data.EndpointSize);           // Endpoint size

        printf("\tPullDownEnableR = 0x%X\n", Data.PullDownEnableR);     // non-zero if pull down enabled
        printf("\tSerNumEnableR = 0x%X\n", Data.SerNumEnableR);     // non-zero if serial number to be used

        printf("\tInvertTXD = 0x%X\n", Data.InvertTXD);         // non-zero if invert TXD
        printf("\tInvertRXD = 0x%X\n", Data.InvertRXD);         // non-zero if invert RXD
        printf("\tInvertRTS = 0x%X\n", Data.InvertRTS);         // non-zero if invert RTS
        printf("\tInvertCTS = 0x%X\n", Data.InvertCTS);         // non-zero if invert CTS
        printf("\tInvertDTR = 0x%X\n", Data.InvertDTR);         // non-zero if invert DTR
        printf("\tInvertDSR = 0x%X\n", Data.InvertDSR);         // non-zero if invert DSR
        printf("\tInvertDCD = 0x%X\n", Data.InvertDCD);         // non-zero if invert DCD
        printf("\tInvertRI = 0x%X\n", Data.InvertRI);               // non-zero if invert RI

        printf("\tCbus0 = 0x%X\n", Data.Cbus0);             // Cbus Mux control
        printf("\tCbus1 = 0x%X\n", Data.Cbus1);             // Cbus Mux control
        printf("\tCbus2 = 0x%X\n", Data.Cbus2);             // Cbus Mux control
        printf("\tCbus3 = 0x%X\n", Data.Cbus3);             // Cbus Mux control
        printf("\tCbus4 = 0x%X\n", Data.Cbus4);             // Cbus Mux control

        printf("\tRIsD2XX = 0x%X\n", Data.RIsD2XX); // non-zero if using D2XX
    }   


exit:
    free(Data.Manufacturer);
    free(Data.ManufacturerId);
    free(Data.Description);
    free(Data.SerialNumber);
    FT_Close(ftHandle0);
    printf("Returning %d\n", retCode);
    return retCode;
}
```

and eeprom-read.c

```
/*
 * FT_EEPROM_Read demonstration.
 * Dumps the EEPROM fields of any connected FTDI device.
 *
 * Copy libftd2xx.a, ftd2xx.h, WinTypes.h into current directory.
 *
 * Compile:
 *     cc eeprom-read.c -L. -lftd2xx -lpthread
 *
 * On Mac, the above line needs these extra dependencies:
 *     -lobjc -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation
 *
 * Run:
 *     sudo ./a.out
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ftd2xx.h"



typedef union Eeprom_Generic
{
    FT_EEPROM_232B     b;
    FT_EEPROM_232R     r;
    FT_EEPROM_232H     singleH;
    FT_EEPROM_2232     dual;
    FT_EEPROM_2232H    dualH;
    FT_EEPROM_4232H    quadH;
    FT_EEPROM_X_SERIES x;
}
Eeprom_Generic;



static const char *deviceName(FT_DEVICE deviceType)
{
    switch(deviceType)
    {
        default:
            return "Unknown";

        case FT_DEVICE_BM:
            return "232 B";

        case FT_DEVICE_2232C:
            return "Dual 232";

        case FT_DEVICE_232R:
            return "232 R";

        case FT_DEVICE_2232H:
            return "Dual Hi-Speed 232";

        case FT_DEVICE_4232H:
            return "Quad Hi-Speed 232";

        case FT_DEVICE_232H:
            return "Hi-Speed 232";

        case FT_DEVICE_X_SERIES:
            return "X Series";
    }
}



static void displayHeader (FT_EEPROM_HEADER *header)
{
    printf("deviceType: %s\n", deviceName(header->deviceType));

    printf("VendorId: %04x\n", header->VendorId);
    printf("ProductId: %04x\n", header->ProductId);
    printf("SerNumEnable: %02x\n", header->SerNumEnable);

    printf("MaxPower: %04x\n", header->MaxPower);
    printf("SelfPowered: %02x\n", header->SelfPowered);
    printf("RemoteWakeup: %02x\n", header->RemoteWakeup);

    printf("PullDownEnable: %02x\n", header->PullDownEnable);
}



static void displayDual (FT_EEPROM_2232 *dual)
{
    printf("AIsHighCurrent: %02x\n", dual->AIsHighCurrent);
    printf("BIsHighCurrent: %02x\n", dual->BIsHighCurrent);

    printf("AIsFifo: %02x\n", dual->AIsFifo);
    printf("AIsFifoTar: %02x\n", dual->AIsFifoTar);
    printf("AIsFastSer: %02x\n", dual->AIsFastSer);
    printf("BIsFifo: %02x\n", dual->BIsFifo);
    printf("BIsFifoTar: %02x\n", dual->BIsFifoTar);
    printf("BIsFastSer: %02x\n", dual->BIsFastSer);

    printf("ADriverType: %02x\n", dual->ADriverType);
    printf("BDriverType: %02x\n", dual->BDriverType);
}



static void displayR (FT_EEPROM_232R *r)
{
    printf("IsHighCurrent: %02x\n", r->IsHighCurrent);

    printf("UseExtOsc: %02x\n", r->UseExtOsc);
    printf("InvertTXD: %02x\n", r->InvertTXD);
    printf("InvertRXD: %02x\n", r->InvertRXD);
    printf("InvertRTS: %02x\n", r->InvertRTS);
    printf("InvertCTS: %02x\n", r->InvertCTS);
    printf("InvertDTR: %02x\n", r->InvertDTR);
    printf("InvertDSR: %02x\n", r->InvertDSR);
    printf("InvertDCD: %02x\n", r->InvertDCD);
    printf("InvertRI: %02x\n", r->InvertRI);
    printf("Cbus0: %02x\n", r->Cbus0);
    printf("Cbus1: %02x\n", r->Cbus1);
    printf("Cbus2: %02x\n", r->Cbus2);
    printf("Cbus3: %02x\n", r->Cbus3);
    printf("Cbus4: %02x\n", r->Cbus4);

    printf("DriverType: %02x\n", r->DriverType);
}



static void displayDualH (FT_EEPROM_2232H *dualH)
{
    printf("ALSlowSlew: %02x\n", dualH->ALSlowSlew);
    printf("ALSchmittInput: %02x\n", dualH->ALSchmittInput);
    printf("ALDriveCurrent: %02x\n", dualH->ALDriveCurrent);
    printf("AHSlowSlew: %02x\n", dualH->AHSlowSlew);
    printf("AHSchmittInput: %02x\n", dualH->AHSchmittInput);
    printf("AHDriveCurrent: %02x\n", dualH->AHDriveCurrent);
    printf("BLSlowSlew: %02x\n", dualH->BLSlowSlew);
    printf("BLSchmittInput: %02x\n", dualH->BLSchmittInput);
    printf("BLDriveCurrent: %02x\n", dualH->BLDriveCurrent);
    printf("BHSlowSlew: %02x\n", dualH->BHSlowSlew);
    printf("BHSchmittInput: %02x\n", dualH->BHSchmittInput);
    printf("BHDriveCurrent: %02x\n", dualH->BHDriveCurrent);

    printf("AIsFifo: %02x\n", dualH->AIsFifo);
    printf("AIsFifoTar: %02x\n", dualH->AIsFifoTar);
    printf("AIsFastSer: %02x\n", dualH->AIsFastSer);
    printf("BIsFifo: %02x\n", dualH->BIsFifo);
    printf("BIsFifoTar: %02x\n", dualH->BIsFifoTar);
    printf("BIsFastSer: %02x\n", dualH->BIsFastSer);
    printf("PowerSaveEnable: %02x\n", dualH->PowerSaveEnable);

    printf("ADriverType: %02x\n", dualH->ADriverType);
    printf("BDriverType: %02x\n", dualH->BDriverType);
}



static void displayQuadH (FT_EEPROM_4232H *quadH)
{
    printf("ASlowSlew: %02x\n", quadH->ASlowSlew);
    printf("ASchmittInput: %02x\n", quadH->ASchmittInput);
    printf("ADriveCurrent: %02x\n", quadH->ADriveCurrent);
    printf("BSlowSlew: %02x\n", quadH->BSlowSlew);
    printf("BSchmittInput: %02x\n", quadH->BSchmittInput);
    printf("BDriveCurrent: %02x\n", quadH->BDriveCurrent);
    printf("CSlowSlew: %02x\n", quadH->CSlowSlew);
    printf("CSchmittInput: %02x\n", quadH->CSchmittInput);
    printf("CDriveCurrent: %02x\n", quadH->CDriveCurrent);
    printf("DSlowSlew: %02x\n", quadH->DSlowSlew);
    printf("DSchmittInput: %02x\n", quadH->DSchmittInput);
    printf("DDriveCurrent: %02x\n", quadH->DDriveCurrent);

    printf("ARIIsTXDEN: %02x\n", quadH->ARIIsTXDEN);
    printf("BRIIsTXDEN: %02x\n", quadH->BRIIsTXDEN);
    printf("CRIIsTXDEN: %02x\n", quadH->CRIIsTXDEN);
    printf("DRIIsTXDEN: %02x\n", quadH->DRIIsTXDEN);

    printf("ADriverType: %02x\n", quadH->ADriverType);
    printf("BDriverType: %02x\n", quadH->BDriverType);
    printf("CDriverType: %02x\n", quadH->CDriverType);
    printf("DDriverType: %02x\n", quadH->DDriverType);
}



static void displaySingleH (FT_EEPROM_232H *singleH)
{
    printf("ACSlowSlew: %02x\n", singleH->ACSlowSlew);
    printf("ACSchmittInput: %02x\n", singleH->ACSchmittInput);
    printf("ACDriveCurrent: %02x\n", singleH->ACDriveCurrent);
    printf("ADSlowSlew: %02x\n", singleH->ADSlowSlew);
    printf("ADSchmittInput: %02x\n", singleH->ADSchmittInput);
    printf("ADDriveCurrent: %02x\n", singleH->ADDriveCurrent);

    printf("Cbus0: %02x\n", singleH->Cbus0);
    printf("Cbus1: %02x\n", singleH->Cbus1);
    printf("Cbus2: %02x\n", singleH->Cbus2);
    printf("Cbus3: %02x\n", singleH->Cbus3);
    printf("Cbus4: %02x\n", singleH->Cbus4);
    printf("Cbus5: %02x\n", singleH->Cbus5);
    printf("Cbus6: %02x\n", singleH->Cbus6);
    printf("Cbus7: %02x\n", singleH->Cbus7);
    printf("Cbus8: %02x\n", singleH->Cbus8);
    printf("Cbus9: %02x\n", singleH->Cbus9);

    printf("FT1248Cpol: %02x\n", singleH->FT1248Cpol);
    printf("FT1248Lsb: %02x\n", singleH->FT1248Lsb);
    printf("FT1248FlowControl: %02x\n", singleH->FT1248FlowControl);

    printf("IsFifo: %02x\n", singleH->IsFifo);
    printf("IsFifoTar: %02x\n", singleH->IsFifoTar);
    printf("IsFastSer: %02x\n", singleH->IsFastSer);
    printf("IsFT1248    : %02x\n", singleH->IsFT1248    );
    printf("PowerSaveEnable: %02x\n", singleH->PowerSaveEnable);

    printf("DriverType: %02x\n", singleH->DriverType);
}



static void displayX (FT_EEPROM_X_SERIES *x)
{
    printf("ACSlowSlew: %02x\n", x->ACSlowSlew);
    printf("ACSchmittInput: %02x\n", x->ACSchmittInput);
    printf("ACDriveCurrent: %02x\n", x->ACDriveCurrent);
    printf("ADSlowSlew: %02x\n", x->ADSlowSlew);
    printf("ADSchmittInput: %02x\n", x->ADSchmittInput);
    printf("ADDriveCurrent: %02x\n", x->ADDriveCurrent);

    printf("Cbus0: %02x\n", x->Cbus0);
    printf("Cbus1: %02x\n", x->Cbus1);
    printf("Cbus2: %02x\n", x->Cbus2);
    printf("Cbus3: %02x\n", x->Cbus3);
    printf("Cbus4: %02x\n", x->Cbus4);
    printf("Cbus5: %02x\n", x->Cbus5);
    printf("Cbus6: %02x\n", x->Cbus6);

    printf("InvertTXD: %02x\n", x->InvertTXD);
    printf("InvertRXD: %02x\n", x->InvertRXD);
    printf("InvertRTS: %02x\n", x->InvertRTS);
    printf("InvertCTS: %02x\n", x->InvertCTS);
    printf("InvertDTR: %02x\n", x->InvertDTR);
    printf("InvertDSR: %02x\n", x->InvertDSR);
    printf("InvertDCD: %02x\n", x->InvertDCD);
    printf("InvertRI: %02x\n", x->InvertRI);

    printf("BCDEnable: %02x\n", x->BCDEnable);
    printf("BCDForceCbusPWREN: %02x\n", x->BCDForceCbusPWREN);
    printf("BCDDisableSleep: %02x\n", x->BCDDisableSleep);

    printf("I2CSlaveAddress: %04x\n", x->I2CSlaveAddress);
    printf("I2CDeviceId: %04x\n", x->I2CDeviceId);
    printf("I2CDisableSchmitt: %02x\n", x->I2CDisableSchmitt);

    printf("FT1248Cpol: %02x\n", x->FT1248Cpol);
    printf("FT1248Lsb: %02x\n", x->FT1248Lsb);
    printf("FT1248FlowControl: %02x\n", x->FT1248FlowControl);

    printf("RS485EchoSuppress: %02x\n", x->RS485EchoSuppress);
    printf("PowerSaveEnable: %02x\n", x->PowerSaveEnable);

    printf("DriverType: %02x\n", x->DriverType);
}



static int readEeprom (DWORD locationId, FT_DEVICE deviceType)
{
    int                  success = 0;
    FT_STATUS            ftStatus;
    FT_HANDLE            ftHandle = (FT_HANDLE)NULL;
    char                 manufacturer[64];
    char                 manufacturerId[64];
    char                 description[64];
    char                 serialNumber[64];
    Eeprom_Generic      *eeprom = NULL;
    FT_EEPROM_HEADER    *header;

    ftStatus = FT_OpenEx((PVOID)(uintptr_t)locationId,
                         FT_OPEN_BY_LOCATION,
                         &ftHandle);
    if (ftStatus != FT_OK)
    {
        printf("FT_OpenEx failed (error code %d)\n", (int)ftStatus);
        goto exit;
    }

    /* Allocate enough to hold biggest EEPROM structure */
    eeprom = calloc(1, sizeof(*eeprom));
    if (eeprom == NULL)
    {
        printf("Allocation failure.\n");
        goto exit;
    }

    /* EEPROM_HEADER is first member of every type of eeprom */
    header = (FT_EEPROM_HEADER *)eeprom;
    header->deviceType = deviceType;

    manufacturer[0] = '\0';
    manufacturerId[0] = '\0';
    description[0] = '\0';
    serialNumber[0] = '\0';

    ftStatus = FT_EEPROM_Read(ftHandle,
                              eeprom,
                              sizeof(*eeprom),
                              manufacturer,
                              manufacturerId,
                              description,
                              serialNumber);
    if (ftStatus != FT_OK)
    {
        printf("FT_EEPROM_Read failed (error code %d)\n", (int)ftStatus);
        goto exit;
    }

    printf("Manufacturer = %s\n", manufacturer);
    printf("ManufacturerId = %s\n", manufacturerId);
    printf("Description = %s\n", description);
    printf("Serial number = %s\n", serialNumber);

    displayHeader((FT_EEPROM_HEADER *)eeprom);

    switch(deviceType)
    {
        default:
        case FT_DEVICE_BM:
            // No further info to display
            break;

        case FT_DEVICE_2232C:
            displayDual(&eeprom->dual);
            break;

        case FT_DEVICE_232R:
            displayR(&eeprom->r);
            break;

        case FT_DEVICE_2232H:
            displayDualH(&eeprom->dualH);
            break;

        case FT_DEVICE_4232H:
            displayQuadH(&eeprom->quadH);
            break;

        case FT_DEVICE_232H:
            displaySingleH(&eeprom->singleH);
            break;

        case FT_DEVICE_X_SERIES:
            displayX(&eeprom->x);
            break;
    }

    printf("\n");

    // Success
    success = 1;

exit:
    (void)FT_Close(ftHandle);
    free(eeprom);
    return success;
}



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FT_STATUS                 ftStatus;
    FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE *devInfo = NULL;
    DWORD                     numDevs = 0;
    int                       i;
    int                       retCode = 0;

    /* Unused parameters */
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    /* Discover how many FTDI devices are connected */
    ftStatus = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(&numDevs);
    if (ftStatus != FT_OK)
    {
        printf("FT_CreateDeviceInfoList failed (error code %d)\n",
               (int)ftStatus);
        goto exit;
    }

    if (numDevs == 0)
    {
        printf("No devices connected.\n");
        goto exit;
    }

    /* Allocate storage */
    devInfo = calloc((size_t)numDevs,
                     sizeof(FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE));
    if (devInfo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Allocation failure.\n");
        goto exit;
    }

    /* Populate the list of info nodes */
    ftStatus = FT_GetDeviceInfoList(devInfo, &numDevs);
    if (ftStatus != FT_OK)
    {
        printf("FT_GetDeviceInfoList failed (error code %d)\n",
               (int)ftStatus);
        goto exit;
    }

    /* Display info (including EEPROM fields) for each connected FTDI device */
    for (i = 0; i < (int)numDevs; i++)
    {
        printf("Device %d:\n",i);
        printf("  Flags = 0x%x\n",devInfo[i].Flags);
        printf("  Type = 0x%x\n",devInfo[i].Type);
        printf("  ID = 0x%04x\n",devInfo[i].ID);
        printf("  LocId = 0x%x\n",devInfo[i].LocId);
        printf("  SerialNumber = %s\n",devInfo[i].SerialNumber);
        printf("  Description = %s\n",devInfo[i].Description);
        printf("  ftHandle = %p\n",devInfo[i].ftHandle);
        if (!readEeprom(devInfo[i].LocId, devInfo[i].Type))
        {
            goto exit;
        }
    }

exit:
    free(devInfo);
    return retCode;
}
```

With reference to the header file [ftd2xx.h](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/windows/dist/drivers/FTDI%20USB%20Drivers/ftd2xx.h). This header file contains is what declares the method that is actually used to get the sensor data. When I run `./read`, the compiled executable from the files above, I get the following output:

```
$ sudo ./read
Library version = 0x10408
Opening port 0
FT_Open succeeded.  Handle is 0x1f24930
FT_GetDeviceInfo succeeded.  Device is type 9.
FT_EE_Read succeeded.

Signature1 = 0
Signature2 = -1
Version = 0
VendorId = 0x0403
ProductId = 0x6015
Manufacturer = 
ManufacturerId = 
Description = 
SerialNumber = 
MaxPower = 90
PnP = 1
SelfPowered = 0
RemoteWakeup = 0
Returning 0
```

Which suggests that the USB port is active and can be read from. My issue is that having looked for sometime I can't find documentation or glean much meaning from the given files as to what all these values mean (for example: what does `Device is type 9` mean?) and although there are more methods in the included in the header file, including a Read File method that should be able to read the stream from the ttyUSB* serial port, many of these are marked as Win32 (using windows.h and I am using Linux).

Essentially my question is:
Are these the correct methods to be using for reading and writing from this sensor with my set-up?
If yes, can you briefly describe how you would do this?
If no, what should I be doing instead?

Apologies for the length of the question or if I have missed something obvious, my background is very much in software so working with this hardware is quite a mystery to me!

Comment: Did you check out https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Knowledgebase/index.html?ft_read.htm ? For sending data you can use FT_Write. Accessing the eeprom is normally not required and only meant for changing certain settings of the device. Generally I would recommend to use the VCP driver instead of D2XX as it is easier to handle for many languages. But for C++ the D2XX is fine.

Comment: and the second example of https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/VC.htm should be quite helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @ChristianB. ! The FT_Read and FT_Write methods you mentioned look to be what I am after. I am considering using VCP instead (both at your recommendation and to remove the need to call rmmod repeatedly on new set-ups), if I were to do this would I still be using the same read and write methods you referred to? Or are they driver specific methods?

Comment: they are d2xx specific calls. With the VCP driver one can address the device as a general com port. For information regarding that topic looking for "access com port ubuntu c++" might be helpful or take a shortcut to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108932/reading-and-writing-to-serial-port-in-c-on-linux .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Christian B says in the comments there is no need to use the D2XX driver.

You can just stick with the default virtual serial port provided by `ftdi_sio` and port Adafruit's [python code](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_BNO055) to C or C++. That should be pretty easy with *termios*.

You can, of course, use that same python code as a reference and work with the D2XX driver but unless you are planning to be using this library a lot or you are working on a commercial product I doubt it would be worth the effort.